# Grouping tabs in WebStorm

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

Is there any opportunity to group tabs in WebStorm / PyCharm?

I know about save context (Alt+Shift+S) and load context (Alt+Shift+L) but it is not quite that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently possible, please follow [IDEA-12130](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12130) and linked tickets for updates